# Method parameter class method type as another parameter type

Tags: typescript

here is a quick example of what I want to do

```
// class for acl will be every time some other class for example "UsersACL", etc....
export class EventsACL{
    test() : {read: true, write: true}
    {
    }
}

// this one is used as a decorator for other methods
function ACL(obj : {
    aclClass : any,
    wantedProprties : aclClass.test
});


// call it
ACL({acl : EventsACL, {read: true, write: false});
```

that means that if I change the EventsACL test function it should dynamically change the request value in wantedProperties.
please I don't want to use predefined interface because I want it to be dynamic for every class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. The part where we get the return type of `test` is slightly hackish but the method won't be called at runtime. You can see it at the [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20EventsACL%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20test()%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20read%3A%20boolean%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20write%3A%20boolean%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20read%3A%20true%2C%20write%3A%20false%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20dummy%20%3D%20(false%20as%20true)%20%26%26%20EventsACL.prototype.test()%3B%0D%0Atype%20ReturnType%20%3D%20typeof%20dummy%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20ACL(obj%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20aclClass%3A%20any%2C%0D%0A%20%20wantedProprties%3A%20ReturnType%0D%0A%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AACL(%7B%0D%0A%20%20aclClass%3A%20EventsACL%2C%0D%0A%20%20wantedProprties%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20read%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20write%3A%20false%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)%3B):

`var dummy = (false as true) && EventsACL.prototype.test();` works because the TypeScript type checker thinks the function is evaluated, but it is transpiled to just `var dummy = false && EventsACL.prototype.test();` in JavaScript so it won't be called at runtime.

```
export class EventsACL {
  test(): {
    read: boolean,
    write: boolean
  } {
    return {
      read: true, write: false
    }
  }
}

// `aclObj` here can be any typed object with a `test` method. Can be EventsACL or UsersACLinstance
var dummy = (false as true) && aclObj.test();
type ReturnType = typeof dummy;

function ACL(obj: {
  aclClass: any,
  wantedProprties: ReturnType
}) {

}

ACL({
  aclClass: EventsACL,
  wantedProprties: {
    read: true,
    write: false
  }
});
```

Comment: Sounds good, if I want to add another property as "both" as string, is it possible?

Comment: Oh it's not good you are using the EventsACL as predefined, I could do something similier like that with an interface

Comment: What do you mean "EventsACL as predefined"? You can replace `EventsACL` with any class and `test` with any method. If you have an `EventsACL` instance you can use `var dummy = (false as true) && aclClass.test();` instead of `var dummy = (false as true) && EventsACL.prototype.test()`;

Comment: Because you assume I'm alway using EventsACL, I need something dynamic

Comment: Not sure I follow. Can you update your question with an example of what you want?

Comment: Still don't get what you mean by "dynamic". I have updated the answer to be a bit more clear. See if it helps.